# Execute a Bash or Python script on DataProc Cluster using DAG

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have created a DAG on the Composer(Airflow), that successfully creates a cluster:

```
with airflow.DAG(dag_id='......',
                default_args=default_args,
                catchup=False,
                description='.......',
                schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    start_of_the_dag = DummyOperator(task_id='start_of_the_dag')

    create_dataproc_cluster = DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
        task_id='............',
        cluster_name='..........',
        storage_bucket=os.environ['gcs_bucket'],
        project_id=os.environ['gcp_project'],
        service_account=os.environ['service_account'],
        master_machine_type='n1-standard-32',
        worker_machine_type='n1-standard-32',
        num_workers=4,
        num_preemptible_workers=0,
        image_version='1.3-debian10',
        metadata={"enable-oslogin":"true"},
        # custom_image=job['cluster_config']['image'],
        internal_ip_only=True,
        region=os.environ['gcp_region'],
        zone=os.environ['gce_zone'],
        subnetwork_uri=os.environ['subnetwork_uri'],
        tags=os.environ['firewall_rules_tags'].split(','),
        autoscaling_policy=None,
        enable_http_port_access=True,
        enable_optional_components=True,
        init_actions_uris=None,
        auto_delete_ttl=3600,
        dag=dag
    )

start_of_the_dag>>create_dataproc_cluster
```

What I want to do is create a python or shell script that will be executed from the master node of the cluster that I just created. Using BashOperator of PythonOperator the execution is made on the composer cluster. (Is that correct?)

To sum up, I want to use an operator after `create_dataproc_cluster` that will execute some commands from the master node of the dataproc cluster.

Comment: Why do not use [initialization actions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions)? It is straight forward with the `init_actions_uris` operator argument

Comment: +1 to @jccampanero solution if you are running a simple script. Is that so ? What "python or shell script" are you trying to execute ? And BTW yes, you are correct, using BashOperator or PythonOperator execution is made on the composer cluster (on workers).